# How can I configure quicklookd32 daemon so that it doesn't fill my system.log?

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, quicklook

I'm running Mac OSX 10.6.7 and recently, I've noticed that my **system.log** file is being filled with **quicklookd32** messages.

The trouble is that whenever I "quick look" a file in the finder, the quicklookd32 daemon will log its contents into the system.log file while rendering it. As one can guess, previewing a large HTML file results in MBs of useless stuff in system.log. It's now at 4GB!

So my question is: how can I prevent this behavior? **Is there a way to tell Quick Look to not log files' contents in system.log?**

Comment: Okay, I narrowed it down to one Quick Look plugin to render MultiMarkdown files (http://fletcherpenney.net/multimarkdown). For those interested, I have logged a ticket on the related github page here: https://github.com/fletcher/peg-multimarkdown/issues/55

Comment: You could try to do what I describe [here](http://superuser.com/questions/278231/how-to-disable-set-logging-level-preferences-per-mac-os-x-application/285384#285384), but I'm not sure whether `quicklookd32` is restarting al the time, rendering this approach useless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick update: as I reported in my comment above, the issue was indeed with the MultiMarkdown QuickLook generator.

Fletcher Penney could fix it real quick, the new version is already available on [Github](https://github.com/fletcher/qlmultimarkdown/downloads)

Thanks,

Rollo

Comment: Please accept your reply to mark this question answered. It was bumped to the front page today, as the system considers it open.