# asl.conf doesn't take an effect on my enviroment OS X Yosemite

Tags: macos, mac, console, syslogd

I'm trying to stop certain application's annoying logging, with no success so far. What I did is those things explained like in this question:

[How to disable/ set logging level /preferences PER Mac OS X application?](https://superuser.com/questions/278231/how-to-disable-set-logging-level-preferences-per-mac-os-x-application/321294#321294)

But in anyways, the modification on asl.conf doesn't take any effect and those apps are still logging. How can I stop the logging of certain applications?

What I tried:

1. Adding some of these lines in asl.conf:

   ? [= Sender Adobe Lightroom] file /dev/null

   ? [= Sender GoogleSoftwareUpdateAgent] ignore

   ? [= Facility libsystem_network] ignore

   ? [CA= Message tcp_connection_destination_prepare_complete] ignore

   ? [S= Sender com.google.Chrome] ignore

   ? [S= Sender com.adobe.Lightroom] ignore
2. sudo killall -HUP syslogd
3. sudo launchctl unload /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.syslogd.plist
4. sudo launchctl load /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.syslogd.plist

Lightroom mobile and Google Update are spewing a large amount of logs and I really want to stop them... Any helps are appriciated, thank you in advance.

Comment: I encounter the same problem. But it seems the rules are actually working, e.g. when I redirect a sender to a file, then this file is created and the log messages are appearing in it. But the messages also continue to spam the system.log too.

Answer (score 0):

It seems adding those things to the global `asl.conf` doesn't has the expected effect the way the rules are handled.

A solution to this problem, I found, is to use separate `asl/*` configuration files for each filter. Those files must be stored in `/etc/asl/`

e.g. to ignore "com.example.Sender" and filter its log spam from system.log we could create a file `/etc/asl/com.example.Sender` with the following content:

```
? [= Sender com.example.Sender] claim only
* ignore
```

The `claim only` for the match (a "Sender" in the example) causes the rules in the master `asl.conf` to be ignored which means things won't end up in `system.log`.

This worked like a charm for me (after I almost went berserk with the main asl.conf).